# Save tags in parent and children of vocabulary with shs module

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 8

How can I save my tags in parent and children of vocabulary with the shs module?

When I save my tag in children with the shs module, I want to show my content in parent and children path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on taxonomy/term/% view, enter contextual filter

> "Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)"

and change the depth settings to -1 and children view will take parent tag nodes too.